# Emacs find-grep-dired then automatically isearch-forward on given regexp

Tags: emacs, grep, dired

I commonly do `find-grep-dired` to find an expression in a project directory. That gives me a nice `dired` view of all the files that contain that expression. But my next step is invariably to open one of those files and do an `isearch-forward` with the same search expression. How can I save myself from typing in the search words twice each time (or more than twice if there are multiple files I want to edit)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work for you:

1. Run `find-grep-dired` as usual
2. Press <kbd>* t</kbd> (dired-toggle-marks) to mark all files.
3. Press <kbd>A</kbd>  to start `dired-do-search`. When prompted, instead of typing, press <kbd>M-p</kbd>, this will bring up your find-grep regexp since both functions use the same prompting history list
4. You will be taken to the first match in the first file. Here's the fun part, simply press <kbd>M-,</kbd> to go to the next match spanning all of your matched files.
5. Profit? (sorry, couldn't resist)

And if you want it all in one shot, here you go:

```
(defun find-grep-dired-do-search (dir regexp)
  "First perform `find-grep-dired', and wait for it to finish.
Then, using the same REGEXP as provided to `find-grep-dired',
perform `dired-do-search' on all files in the *Find* buffer."
  (interactive "DFind-grep (directory): \nsFind-grep (grep regexp): ")
  (find-grep-dired dir regexp)
  (while (get-buffer-process (get-buffer "*Find*"))
    (sit-for 1))
  (with-current-buffer "*Find*"
    (dired-toggle-marks)
    (dired-do-search regexp)))
```

Comment: `dired-do-search` is bound to `A` in dired buffers.

Comment: M-, to go forward, whats the key binding to go back? i.e. to prev occurrence?

Answer (score 3):

You can store the search string you use in find-grep-dired in the kill ring (C-SPACE C-a M-w). Then you do the search in the files using the string from the kill ring (C-s M-y). M-y will  yank the last string of killed text.

You can display other (useful) bindings for isearch-forward using C-h k C-s.

Comment: Thanks, that's one way, certainly. I was hoping for something a little less involved, like a single binding to isearch for the last search string.

Answer (score 2):

How about a different approach?  Try using `M-x igrep-find` from the [`igrep.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/igrep.el) package.

By default it searches for *all* occurrences of the pattern, but you could change the behavior to just find the first such occurrence with:

```
(setq igrep-options "-i -m 1")   ;; I like -i for case-insensitivity
```

This will result in a *compilation* style buffer (named `*igrep*`) with a single line for each file, and when you click on the line (or do <kbd>C-x `</kbd>), you'll automatically be put on the line which has the match.  Plus, you can see the matching line in the `*igrep*` buffer.

Obviously, if you want to see more than one match per file, change the number after the `-m`, or omit that part altogether.

Comment: I tried that but got an error: find /Users/reed/sb/ampms/app -type d \( -name RCS -o -name CVS -o -name SCCS \) -prune -o -type f \! -name \*\~ \! -name \*\,v \! -name s.\* \! -name .\#\*  -print0 | xargs -0 -e grep -n  -e test  /dev/null
xargs: illegal option -- e
usage: xargs [-0opt] [-E eofstr] [-I replstr [-R replacements]] [-J replstr]
             [-L number] [-n number [-x]] [-P maxprocs] [-s size]
             [utility [argument ...]]

Comment: @Reed It looks like your xargs doesn't support `-e`, unsure why.  You can avoid using xargs by setting `(setq igrep-find-use-xargs nil)`.  Or download a newer version of xargs (in findutils).

Comment: I'm on OSX. Perhaps that's why.

Comment: I installed findutils from homebrew: `brew install findutils` and changed my $PATH to make the /usr/local/bin/xargs load before the system /usr/bin/xargs like this `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH` and now it works great. I do wish it could use ido-mode to find the starting search directory.